# Query Feature Class Service - Portal display

Tags: query-layer, arcgis-portal

I am new to arcgis and i have tried to use the right terminology.

I have a Query Feature Class consisting of Polygons and points referrencing a non-geodatabase that I have published as a service via arcmap (10.3.1). This service appears to have published correctly and when querying the layer directly via a browser everything appears to work correctly, as it does inside arcmap prior to publishing.

When I import this into a map in arcgis-portal the service displays as I expect the polygons are projected over New Zealand as expected.

However when I use the data table in the map and "centre on selection" from the table drop down the map zooms to Italy when the polygon was displaying on New Zealand, with a blue outline of the shape I have selected over italy.

This is strange as when I import the service the polygon itself displays correctly as does the popup. This behaviour also appears using the query object in the web app builder. It only seems to appear on service based from queries and not when i publish the service via a file-geodatabase.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

[image: These are how the geometires look intially]

[image: This is what happens when you center on selection or use the query widget the development tool]

Comment: Assuming by "Query Feature Class", you mean [Query Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/creating-a-query-layer.htm) Are you certain that the field you've designated as the unique value field has no duplicate values?

Comment: yes i have added a int field as an identity in the table i query. and in the service this is set to a esriFieldTypeOID

Comment: Do you have any geometries in your table that are over Italy?

Comment: Have you checked the projection of the query layer as well as the projection of the data frame?

Comment: Along the same lines as @MickyT - this sounds like an issue with the transformation between two projections. Can you check the basemap projection that is used on your map (or is it a default ArcGIS Online basemap?), what's the WKID?  And of your published service based on the query feature class, what projection is given in the service definition? Ideally these should match, or have a transformation between the two which the Portal viewer can handle.  Unfortunately the way Portal handles projections isn't ideal.

Comment: Hi Kirk, no italy geometries

Comment: This is what the projection is set to automatically from my query layer



PROJCS["NZGD_2000_New_Zealand_Transverse_Mercator",GEOGCS["GCS_NZGD_2000",DATUM["D_NZGD_2000",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",1600000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",173.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Comment: Kes has nailed it, it was my basemap when i used a specific New zealand basemap it all worked.

http://arcgisonline.co.nz/arcgis/rest/services/Generic/newzealand/MapServer

how does he get the points?

Comment: @kes Would you like to write that up as an answer?

Comment: Thanks @MickyT, Gareth  - if you would prefer to use one of the ArcGIS Online basemaps in your map you can also publish the map service in a different projection as in my answer. It looks like the conversion from [NZGD2000 is straightforward](http://www.linz.govt.nz/regulatory/25000) and can be selected in ArcMap as the transformation 'NZGD_2000_To_WGS_1984_1', it's odd that Portal didn't apply this by default?

Comment: "tried to use the right terminology" lol, Esri can't even decide what to call things and they keep changing their terminology. +1 just for that intro line, don't worry about it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When viewing a feature or map service in the ArcGIS Portal Map Viewer if the mapservice projection doesn't match that of the basemap the viewer will try to re-project the layer using your Geometry Service*.

If this doesn't work you can either;

1. Change the Basemap to one that matches your mapservice, or
2. Project the data to match the basemap and publish, or
3. Project the mapservice to match your basemap when publishing

**Changing the Basemap**

The default ArcGIS Online basemaps are in the Web Mercator Projection (WKID:3857), if your data is country specific you may be able to use a base map for that country or projection.

**Project your data to match the Basemap**

If your data is static or changes infrequently you could re-project to feature class to match the desired basemap, using the [Project Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm). Be sure to specify a transformation if required for your project.

For advanced users with Query Layers your DBMS may offer native projection functions, e.g. for [Oracle Spatial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96630/sdo_cs_ref.htm).

**Reprojecting your Mapservice to match the basemap**

Publishing your Mapservice in a different projection allows you to choose the best transformation for your data.

1. In ArcMap, set the Projection of the map document Data frame and specify the desired transformation.  For the ArcGIS Online default basemaps use the Web Mercator Projection (wkid:3857).
2. Publish the map service and check the rest service definition is displaying the spatial reference code for the projection you specified.  The query layer will be transformed by your ArcGIS Server instance on the fly.

If your mapservice is always used in this projection this should perform better than clients going via the Geometry Service to project the data.

*Geometry Services*

The re-projection in portal will use the Geometry Service from your [organisation's utility  services](http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/linux/configure-services.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_82887E5A1A214E709186C07CB7F3B118). If strange things are happening first check that this is setup and running.

The Geometry Service uses default transformations which may be not be appropriate for your projections, and unfortunately it isn't yet possible to [configure or specify the transformations used by the geometry service](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/19607).